# Need kind assistance in a date fixing code

Tags: shell, date, ubuntu, csh

I am trying to run a cash (C Shell script) in my windows Ubuntu but everytime it is showing this error:

```
date: invalid option -- 'v'
Try 'date --help' for more information.**
```

The code-line was this:

```
set query_day=`date -v -"$i"d +"%Y-%m-%d"`
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I solve this issue?

Comment: It seems that `date -v` is not a valid command. It looks like the intent of the command is to format the date? The notation `-"$i"d +"%Y-%m-%d"` is a little weird. Do you see the command you might be looking for when you type `date --help` as suggested? Could you tell us an example of what the expected result would look like?

Comment: `-v` is not a standard option, and it is unavailable in Ubuntu. Note: macos use it to "adjust" the date by (in your case `-$i` days).